# Mysql | Sort by time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with my query, I have a field in the never table which is called: `appto_orario` of type time, what I would like to do is sort the results by time so if I have a result that is at 15:00 and one at 14:00 I would like the second to be displayed earlier than the first one I wrote, this with my query it doesn't happen, I don't understand why

```
$oggi = date('Y/m/d');
SELECT *
FROM appuntamento
LEFT JOIN richieste
ON appuntamento.appto_id_richiesta = richieste.ID_Richiesta

LEFT JOIN pre_appuntamento
ON appuntamento.appto_pre_appuntamento = pre_appuntamento.ID_pre_appuntamento

WHERE appuntamento.appto_id_richiesta = richieste.ID_Richiesta
AND appto_data = '$oggi'
AND appto_stato = 'NC'
LIMIT 3
ORDER BY appto_orario DESC
```

or

```
TIME(appto_orario)
```

if i make var_dump i have: bool(false)

image of data: [image: image data]

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have upload a pic of my data

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause should be after the `ORDER BY` clause. The `LIMIT` clause should be the last thing in the SQL `SELECT` statement.

Comment: With the `DESC` in your order by, the result would be as you show with highest values first. Use `ASC` instead to get earlier values first.

Comment: I'm surprised that the condition `appto_data = '$oggi'` is true since the field doesn't have slashes, and your variable `$oggi` does.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i don't understand Sloan, can you tell me again, please

Comment: Which part of the three are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I don't understand why you are surprised if with dates specifying the format I get the current date and comparing with the results of the db which are in the same format why shouldn't it give me that the condition is true?

Comment: Sorry, images are hard to see, and I didn't notice the slashes in the output. Always better to show results, code, etc as text rather than images.

Comment: @SloanThrasher ah ok no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest that either you want to order by time ascending:

```
ORDER BY appto_orario
```

Or, perhaps you want to find the latest 3 records, but then order that 3 record result set ascending:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- your current query
    ORDER BY appto_orario DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ORDER BY
    appto_orario;
```

Comment: i solved my question cause the solution was order by before limit: ORDER BY appto_orario ASC
LIMIT 3, i m waiting 10 min and flag your answer correct, thanks

Comment: @AMCode Note that you _don't_ need to ever use `ORDER BY ... ASC`, because the default order is always ascending.  In fact, I would say that it is convention to avoid using `ASC` unless there is a really good reason to use it.

Comment: I generally always add "ASC", as its then always clear the intention, regardless of what database will do by default.

Comment: @IncredibleHat That could be a good question to ask on SO, assuming it hasn't already been debated both ways `:-)`

Comment: Haha yes! I'm sure its a preference matter these days (especially with mysql). My habit may have stemmed from early days of using Oracle, where you had to explicitly tell it what you wanted to do for everything.